# how to load a image from web in java

Tags: java, image

I need to load an image from a web in a simple Java stand alone aplication. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://host/theimage.jpg");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

is that enough to start you? Don't know what you want to do from there.

Comment: URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

Comment: you can do `Files.copy(url.openStream(), new File("filename.jpg").toPath());` to store it on disk(watch out for null-pointers).

Answer (score 60):

You can load an image using

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png"));
```

For methods how to display the loaded image, see the Sun ["Working with images" tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/index.html).

Comment: This results in `null` if the URL has http status code `301` or `302`. If so, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951696/java-urlconnection-get-the-final-redirected-url.

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation at [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)).

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html).

Find the URL to the image, and you can get an inputstream feeding you the image data, plus you'll get the content-type etc. so you can correctly handle it once you've downloaded it.

[Here's](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) some sample code. You may also need to call getResponseHeaders() on the [GetMethod](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/GetMethod.html) to identify the image type.