# Load image from URL and limit the size of the file

Tags: java, image, url, download

I have found how to load an image from an Url using this question on SO : [how to load a image from web in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926938/how-to-load-a-image-from-web-in-java)

But I'd like to limit the size of the file being loaded because all the answers have this in common : if a user give the url to a one terabyte file, it will crashes my server :/

How can I limit the size of the file being downloaded ?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: *"if a user give the url to a one terabyte file, it will crashes my server"*  Why does it crash your server?  Is the resource coming *from* your server?  Is your server acting as a proxy (getting it from another server) for the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to guarantee you won't download a large file is to use [IOUTils.read](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20char[],%20int,%20int)):

```
    int maxDownload = 1024*1024*2;
    URL website = new URL("http://www.wswd.net/testdownloadfiles/200MB.zip");

    byte[] outBytes = new byte[maxDownload];
    InputStream stream = website.openStream();

    IOUtils.read(stream, outBytes, 0, maxDownload);

    if (stream.read() != -1) {
        System.out.println("File too big");
    } 

    IOUtils.write(outBytes, new FileOutputStream("200MB.zip"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Following the code you got from your previous answer...

```
URL url = new URL("http://host/theimage.jpg");
URLConnection conn = new URLConnection(url);

// now you get the content length
int cLength = conn.getContentLength();

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

You can find more on the methods of [URLConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29) here.

Do take into consideration that this will honor only the HTTP headers given by the other end, there is no reason it will comply or be honest about it. So if you're playing on the real safe and "do-not-hack-me" side you should inspect the `InputStream` as it is coming and terminate it after a fixed amount of data.

Comment: The content length is given before downloading ? (in the headers)?

Comment: By the way, I get a "Cannot instantiate the type URLConnection" :/

Comment: @cx42net generally content length is given before. For instance, when you download a file with your browser (a large one) it can give you the percentage remaining (generally with an estimation of the time to complete) or not. If it does give you those number is because the connection on the other end has honored the HTTP headers and sent the length on the headers.

Comment: and @Jack Edmonds has gone all the way to give you the paranoid solution I was talking about.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to check that the content-length was less than the maximum number of bytes @cx42net wanted to read (e.g. `if (cLength>1000000000000)throw new FileTooBigException();`)?

Comment: @JackEdmonds, on my answer I just gave a broad indication on how to obtain the contentLenght as the OP would presumably be able to go from there. As per my comments I was also saying that all in all contentLenght is just an HTTP header and can be easily tampered with and advised the OP on your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *guarantee* that you won't download more than a certain amount, you will need to wrap `InputStream` with your own implementation.  Essentially create a new class

```
/**
 * Limits the amount of data you can read.
 * Warning: this only partially implements all the necessary methods.
 *     You will need to implement the rest that I was too lazy to include.
 */
public class InputStreamLimiter extends InputStream {
    private final InputStream wrappedInputStream;
    private int bytesRead;
    private final maxBytes;
    public InputStreamLimiter(final InputStream stream, final int maxBytes)
    {
        this.maxBytes=maxBytes;
        this.wrappedInputStream=stream;
    }
    public int available(){return wrappedInputStream.available();}
    public void close(){wrappedInputStream.close();}
    //Continue wrapping methods until you reach the read() methods.

    /**
     * Provide your own implementation of the read methods that make sure you don't attempt to read too many bytes.
     * This method crashes if you attempt to read too much.
     */
    public int read(final byte b[]) throws IOException {
        if (b.length + bytesRead > maxBytes) throw new IOException("File was too big.");
        else return wrappedInputStream.read(b);
    }
}
```

Then use that class like so:

```
ImageIO.read(new InputStreamLimiter(new URL("http://server/image.png").openStream(),MAX_BYTES)));
```

Comment: Your answer is really great and interesting, if I could select two answers, ours would have been in, but unforntutaley, the accepted one fit better my needs for now (maybe I'll use yours laters). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "mark" method on InputStream and set readlimit.