# Fetch Friends profile image from restfb

Tags: java, image, profile, restfb

I am using below code to get profile image of friends using Resfb. I get the response too with name id and image. Please some one help me asap on how to get the image from this data.

**Code**

```
Connection<User> myFriends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class,Parameter.with("fields", "id, name,picture"));
```

**Response**

```
"data":[{"id":"554603591","name":"Arjun Rao","picture":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/211391_554603591_2022493_q.jpg"}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use restfb to parse Json-Objects:

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(SERVER_RESPONSE);
try {
     String pictureURL = obj.getString("picture");
    }
catch(JsonException e) {
       // key 'picture' not found
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know how to parse the response?

If yes, just get the URL of the image, open a `URLConnection` and do a `getInputStream()` (the code for this is [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926938/how-to-load-a-image-from-web-in-java)).

With the `InputStream`, you can save to a file or send it to the client.

Comment: Consider adding context for the link. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for details why.

Comment: I think this is a fine answer. I'm not here to judge whether it's right or wrong, but in terms of *quality*, it looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that RestFB isn't up to date in sense how Graph API returns (some objects) inside "data" object?

I managed to work-around with this custom class:

```
public class DataPictureHolder {
    @Facebook("data")
    public ProfilePictureSource picture;
}
```