# How to update our android webview when a open webview with a url is being loaded with another url?

Tags: android, url, webview, loading

I would like to load to know an url been updated in webview over previously loaded url.How can I detect second url is been loaded completely, any snippets or examples will be very much helpful for resolving this.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Call again

mWebView.loadUrl("second url");

Comment: why don't you give final redirected url to your webview . this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951696/java-urlconnection-get-the-final-redirected-url

Comment: Raghu my first window needs to get input from user which will be used in second window..On the whole its mandatory to have load one by one inside same webview with self-redirection..Hope you get it..