# URLConnection.getURL method

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-redirect, urlconnection, redirect

I would like to have a second opinion on a small piece of Java code.

Will the method below **always** return an output string equal to the input string?

```
private static String func(final String url)
{
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    ...
    ...
    return con.getURL().toString();
}
```

The question refers to **all** possible scenarios, such as automatic redirection, etc.

Comment: Added 'con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)'; does the answer still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [URLConnection.getUrl() implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URLConnection.java#URLConnection.getURL%28%29), you can see that it returns the original URL passed to the constructor.

[HttpURLConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java) also doesn't change the original url.

To get the destination URL of a redirect you're supposed to call con.getHeaderField("Location"); - see for example: [Retrieve the final location of a given URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806617/retrieve-the-final-location-of-a-given-url-in-java)

So you get the original URL until you call `connect()` or some other method that results in establishing a connection.

If you set `((HttpURLConnection)con).setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);` then after `connect()` if it really redirects you'll get the destination URL.

Redirect may not automatically happen for example when the protocol changes (e.g. http -> https).

Comment: are you sure? what if I call con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)?

Comment: in that case, before you call connect() or some other method that causes a connect you'll get the original URL. After connect() with follow redirects true you'll get the destination URL if it really followed the redirect (it won't for example if the protocol changes: http -> https).

Comment: So basically, what you're saying here means that the answer above is incorrect, right?

Comment: yes, added the other case too now. Btw, it's difficult to verify because HttpURLConnection is just an abstract class and I guess the actual implementation is platform dependent... so the exact behavior may actually be different on different platforms...